# Как получить Google Drive API File ID после того как он уже был загружен на Google Drive ? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive

**Для начала я понял, что нужно задать поиск:**

```
private static Query[] sQueries = new Query[] {

                // files with a title containing 'inventory_premium'
                new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, "inventory_premium")).build(),

                // files with text/plain or text/html mimetype
                new Query.Builder()
                        .addFilter(Filters.or(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/html"),
                                Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "application/x-sqlite3")))
                        .build()};
```

**Каков следущий шаг для поиска Id файла загруженного в папку, видимую только моим приложением?**